# Remove unique atrribute from a column in SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have a table structure called AC_COMPANY:

```
CREATE TABLE AC_COMPANY
(
    ID NUMERIC(19,0) NOT NULL,
    ADDRESS VARCHAR(255),
    COMPANY_PREFERENCES NUMERIC(19,0),
    COUNTRY VARCHAR(64),
    CREATION_DATE DATETIME,
    ENABLE_SELF_ONBOARD TINYINT,
    hubCompanyuseDefaultLogoInAppHeader TINYINT,
    IMAGE_IDENTIFIER INT,
    MODIFIED_DATE DATETIME,
    NAME VARCHAR(48),
    PHONE_NUMBER VARCHAR(64),
    PRIMARY_CONTACT VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    STATUS INT NOT NULL,
    tradingPartner VARBINARY(255),
    URL VARCHAR(255),
    USE_DEFAULT_LOGO_IN_HEADER TINYINT,
    CREATED_BY VARCHAR(255),
    MODIFIED_BY VARCHAR(255),
    PRIMARY KEY (ID),
    UNIQUE (PRIMARY_CONTACT),
    UNIQUE (NAME)
);
```

How can I remove Unique attribute from Column PRIMARY_CONTACT.

Comment: `ALTER TABLE DROP CONSTRAINT`. You'll need to find the auto-generated name first, in `sys.key_constraints`. To avoid that in the future, use the full `CONSTRAINT UQ_AC_COMPANY_PRIMARY_CONTACT UNIQUE(PRIMARY_CONTACT)` syntax in the `CREATE` statement.

Comment: Unique is not an attribute of a column. It's a constraint. You need to find it's name and then you can use alter table to drop it.

Comment: I have used a stored procedure to print constraint but it return no result.@JeroenMostert.

cAN YOU PLS GIVE THE QUERY HOW TO DELETE WITHOUT KNOWING CONTRAINT NAME

Comment: Then don't use that procedure because it stinks? `SELECT * FROM sys.key_constraints WHERE [parent_object_id] = OBJECT_ID('AC_COMPANY') and [type] = 'UQ'` will list all unique constraints for a table. (But not their columns, that takes a much more involved query.)

Comment: it will give result of all column in which unique constraint are present now how can i identify on primary_contact and delete it .Can u pls give me a single query because i have to used in various machine and i don't have acces to them. @JeroenMostert

Comment: David Browne's picked up the slack. If you don't know the name, there is no *single* query that will do it -- to do it automatically, you need dynamic SQ in *combination* with a query to find it.

Comment: Are you _certain_ you should drop that constraint? Constraints exist for a very good reason. For example if you allow duplicates in this table, any join on this column will now also yield duplicates

Answer (score 0):

Here's a query to retrieve the unique constraints with their columns.

```
select i.name constraint_name, object_name(i.object_id) table_name, c.name column_name, ic.key_ordinal index_key_ordinal
from sys.indexes i
join sys.index_columns ic
  on i.object_id = ic.object_id
 and i.index_id = ic.index_id
join sys.columns c
  on c.object_id = ic.object_id
 and c.column_id = ic.column_id
where i.is_unique_constraint = 1
  and i.object_id=object_id('AC_COMPANY')
order by table_name, index_key_ordinal
```

Comment: @davidbrone now how can i delete  a contraint on Primary contact

Comment: Once you discover the name of the constraint you want to drop then just `alter table ac_company drop constraint UQ__AC_COMPA__85B2494D09E36285`

Comment: 'constraintUQ__AC_COMPA__85B2494DE67823A9' is not a constraint. error is coming @david Browne

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @table_name sysname = 'AC_COMPANY';
-- alphabetically sorted, comma-separated list of columns that make up the constraint
declare @column_names nvarchar(max) = 'PRIMARY_CONTACT';

declare @constraint_name sysname;
;with key_constraints as (
  select kc.[name], stuff((
    select ',' + COL_NAME(ic.[object_id], ic.column_id)
    from sys.index_columns ic 
    where ic.[object_id] = i.[object_id] and ic.index_id = i.index_id
    order by 1
    for xml path('')
  ), 1, 1, '') as column_names
  from sys.key_constraints kc
  join sys.indexes i on 
      i.[object_id] = kc.parent_object_id and kc.unique_index_id = i.index_id
  where kc.parent_object_id = OBJECT_ID(@table_name)
)
select @constraint_name = [name]
from key_constraints
where column_names = @column_names;

declare @sql nvarchar(max);
select @sql = replace(replace(
    'alter table $t drop constraint $c', 
    '$t', quotename(@table_name)), 
    '$c', quotename(@constraint_name))
;

print @sql;
exec (@sql);
```

And this is why, if you can help it, you *always* give your constraints unique, systematic names so you don't have to discover them at runtime.